# How to generate NA in a list of data frames with unequal rows

Tags: r, list

I have a list of data frame that have unequal no of rows. I want to generate NA in all my dataframe so that they have equal no of rows in it.

```
l=list(data.frame(a=1:5,b=4:8), data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20))
m=max(sapply(l, nrow))
```

This works for length but not for rows.

```
lapply(l, function(x) { nrow(x) <- m  })
```

Comment: `lapply(l, function(x)as.data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(x),matrix(data=NA,nrow=(m-nrow(x)), ncol=ncol(x))))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `[.data.frame` because if you extract more rows than what's existing in a `data.frame` (or other vector), they will be filled with `NA` by default.

```
lapply(l, function(x) x[seq_len(m),])
```

Or if you want to reset the row.names afterwards:

```
lapply(l, function(x){ x <- x[seq_len(m),]; row.names(x) <- NULL; x})
```

As mentioned, the same happens with simple vectors:

```
x <- 1:5
x[1:10]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have really massive lists, a for loop would also work fine here and would be pretty easy to read:

```
l <- list(data.frame(a=1:5,b=4:8), data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20))
m <- max(sapply(l, nrow))

for (i in seq_along(l)) {
    entry <- l[[1]]

    # skip entry if no rows need to be added
    if (nrow(entry) == m) {
        next
    }

    # otherwise add NA rows
    rows_to_add <- matrix(rep(NA, (m - nrow(entry)) * ncol(entry)), 
                          ncol=ncol(entry))
    colnames(rows_to_add) <- colnames(entry)

    l[[i]] <- rbind(entry, rows_to_add)
}
```

Comment: Would like to stick to apply function as they better in terms of code readability. Thanks.

Comment: @docendodiscimus In this case the matrix of NAs (`rows_to_add`) will get coerced into a `data.frame` upon calling `rbind`, so it shouldn't affect the elements of the data.frame.